# PHP: Load any div content by clicking <a> tag by corresponding DIV id="" in ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, html, load

I developed a SLIDING page site which has only one index page and 4-5 different DIV section distinguished by DIV id, here is the link: http://gosick.tk/
*name: 08093103002
pass: mak*

but it take quite a long time to load because the whole site is only 1 page and the full page is actually 9200 PX;

now I want to load each DIVISION by id="" wise by AJAX when I click the menu at a time or 
pls give me any solution that I can speed up my content load during form action urgent

Answer (score 0):

"now I want to load each DIVISION by AJAX "

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.html',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        var div = $('#loadDivId', $(html)).addClass('classname');
        $('#wheretoloadId').html(div);
    }
    });
```

Edit : This works only if  your div is a part of ajax response?

Comment: can you be more specific? because I can't use this solution ..... actually I am too dumb about AJAX or JS don't know how to place this code specifically in my CODING :(

Comment: well, i gave you the way. put some efforts , implementation is your business. right

Answer (score 0):

this will open the link of anchor tag in the div content

```
 <script> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('a').each(function(){ 
   $(this).on("click",function(e) {

   console.log(e);
  e.preventDefault();
   $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
   });
   });
   });
   </script>
```

Comment: an you be more specific? because I can't use this solution ..... actually I am too dumb about AJAX or JS don't know how to place this code specifically in my CODING :(

actually I want to load a part of DIV without loading the whole page! And I need full coding integration example support pls